# What time travel theory does the Star Trek saga use?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel

The question comes to mind when the Enterprise engages into warp drive.  The way warp drive works, as I understand it, is that depending on the amount of energy expended by the Enterprise determines a specific warp factor the Enterprise is traveling.  That aside, each warp factor is a measure in multiples of light speed.

In context to Einstien's thoery of relativity, there's a sort of consensus in that as you aproach the the speed of light, time starts slowing down.  Furthermore, at the point at which exceed the speed of light point time travel occurs.  **Does Star Trek use a different theory?**

Comment: Einstein never said that exceeding speed of light would make you travel in time. Relativistic theories say that nothing can exceed speed of light. If you are exceeding speed of light, you are simply smashing the validity of those theories at that point of speed. For instance, those theories are not valid on Warp 2.

Comment: The 'slowing down' you are talking about is better known as [Time Dilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation), and has been demonstrated many times.  But the same theory that predicted it ALSO says you won't be able to exceed light speed, as your power requirements to accelerate the ever-increasing mass will quickly grow beyond what is possible, becoming effectively infinite for that last few miles an hour needed to reach light speed.

Comment: @SachinShekhar I am aware that Einstein didn't exactly make the claim which is why I was careful to use the term, *there's a sort of consensus*.  Clearly the Star Trek series breaks Einstein's theory as Keith H Weston eludes to.

Comment: Star Trek doesn't break Einstein's theory.. With warp bubble, spacetime is no longer uniform in vicinity of starship for which Einstein's theory (and physics) isn't defined.

Comment: Who says Einstein is right?  It's impossible to prove one way or another at our current state of technology.  I think that's why Star Trek avoids directly addressing the subject.

Comment: @bblake einstein is right because your gps works. if einstein was wrong it wouldn't work. simple. einsteins theory (restricted relativity) only isnt valid on quanta level. as to the others, it's impossible to exceed the speed of light, according to einstein, because with higher speed you get more mass, so more energy is needed to push you through. technically F=dp. p=gamma*mv. the only way to reach light speed is to have no mass in which case E=pc. so you just gotta lose all mass and get enough energy so that p=E/c

Comment: @Shingetsu Except that Newton was right for a long time before Einstein's came up with relativity.  It's quite possible that there's something more complex going on, that relativity is simply the best answer we have for it.  Einstein was more right than Newton, there's a fair chance that someone else will be more right than Einstein.

Comment: @Izkata Newton is still correct provided the problem domain is not relativistic and quantum..

Comment: @BBlake I say, Einstein is right. And, Star Trek is supporting it. If not, Warp tech was never introduced. All they needed to tell their impulse drive is accounted for that travel..

Comment: @BBlake Also, remember.. All physics laws (not just relativistic theories) are valid only if spacetime is uniform. This is the problem domain of physics. That's why it's called dimension. You don't need warp drive to prove whole physics wrong.. Just switch to non-inertial reference frame. Done! Warp drive is not smashing Einstein because its simply not moving with spacetime, but its distorting spacetime field with warp bubble.

Comment: @Izkata technically Newton's laws were an approximation for large distances. For example, if you use it to guess where the moon is, the result will vary by 15 meters from reality every day. Einstein's theory guesses it exactly, as well as the movement of even far more far away objects. It's not the perfect theory because it doesn't work on quanta level. However, because your GPS works, that IS how it works in macroscopic levels. We just have to enlarge the theory to fit with nuclea. Also, Sachin is right about the uniform spacetime, distortion is but a part of it.

Comment: @Shingetsu You realize you just agreed with me, right?  Newton was correct in his day because there was nothing better.  Einstein is more correct than Newton because the results from relativity are more accurate and work on a greater scale.  However, there _can_ be someone in the future who is _more_ correct than Einstein because their theory may encompass not only all of relativity, but also work at the microscopic level.  (GPS isn't perfect anyway; accuracy is around 5 meters)

Comment: @Izkata the reason GPS accuracy is 5 meters is due to the electromagnetic disturbance of the earth's field. If Einstein was wrong or inexact in the macroscopic level it wouldn't work at all. Newton was never exact at all, however. I do agree that we can improve on Einstein's theorem. I do not agree that it's to be replaced by another one. Newton's theory is nonexistent in Einstein's in most cases. Even the energy graph of the two are of the different degree (1st and 2nd).

Comment: @SachinShekhar Einstein's dilation formula, when applied to speeds greater than C, definitely does directly imply T≤0. (Because, if one plugs in a value higher than 1 for fraction of C, one's resulting perceived time is a negative number.)

Comment: @aramis You can't apply relativistic formulae to speeds greater than c. This part limits it mathematically: `(1- (v/c)^2)^(1/2)`. If v is greater than c, (v/c) will be greater than 1. Squaring will make it more greater. Subtracting it from 1 will result negative number. And, if you are good at kid maths, you can't find real square root of a negative number.

Comment: Lol, this is one of those questions when you should narrow it down to what episode you're asking about

Comment: What time travel theory does the Star Trek saga use? Pretty much all of them, at some point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Canonical *Star Trek* has never addressed, on screen, exactly what is being warped (space? time? both?), how warp drive works, or why there doesn't seem to be any meaningful time dilation effects. *The Next Generation*, which began a trend of trying to at least talk about the technology (usually in made up terminology) introduced the notion of a "warp field" that surrounds the ship, a notion also used in non-canonical *Star Trek* novels even before TNG, especially those by Diane Duane.

Exactly how this warp field works is, again, left largely to the imagination, but the end result is clear: no one in *Star Trek* ever worries about time dilation or other relativistic effects. Even ships traveling at sub-light speeds on impulse drive never worry about it, suggesting that some of the warp field's magic is used even sub-light.

So, it's really not that *Star Trek* denies relativity; it's that there's a technology that allows it to be sidestepped, and since we have no idea in the real world how to do that yet, the mechanism for how it's done is simply glossed over.

Comment: somehow this sounds a lot like the `mass effect drive` :o I guess now we know where it camr from =3

Comment: In several of the non-screen (but still canon) sources, including the *TNG Technical Manual*, it is mentioned that ships travelling at impulse *are* affected by time dilation; it's even a part of the plot in a few books, including *Star Trek Enterprise: The Romulan War: To Brave the Storm*. This just never came up in any of the TV shows or movies; they just never travel at impulse long or fast enough for it to be an issue.

Answer (score 7):

Warp drive is a type of [Alcubierre drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive), which works by distorting space around a small area.

No relativistic effects are felt because the ship itself isn't moving at relativistic speeds.  Space is being distorted around the ship instead.

However, in TOS 1x06, [The Naked Time](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Naked_Time), they execute a controlled implosion of the engines and, according to Spock, "travel faster than is possible, for normal space".  This caused them to travel backwards in time.  They were later able to duplicate the effect with the [Slingshot effect](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Slingshot_effect), also known as the light-speed breakaway factor.

As a side note, warp factor isn't a multiple of the speed of light. [The equations used are a bit more complex](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Warp_factor). (See the Background Information section for examples and actual equations)

Comment: Best answer I see here. Sadly TOS 1x06, as you said, disagrees with restricted relativity, though it may be a matter of the usual space distortion passing in the (vague and theoretical) hyperspace in which differences in speed can twist around time. (I've done a lot of physics and yes, hyperspace really exists in current theories. It's outside spacetime though.)

Answer (score 0):

According to scientists, in real life if a crew were travelling at speed appraching the speed of light time would be slowed down so from the outside looking into the spaceship everything would appear to be moving in slow motion, but from the inside looking at the universe everthing would appear to be moving quickly.

In Star Trek warp 1 is the speed of light, but even at speeds of warp 6 and higher we have seen all generations of the Star Trek universe have conversations via the viewscreen with people on a planet surface where the person at the other end appears to be moving in normal time.

Although Star Trek sometimes takes inspiration from real life science, it appears that they ignore or at least work around Einstein's Theory of Relativity or that it simply doesn't apply to warp speed travel.

Comment: That's incorrect. In real life if a crew would travel at speed nearing the speed of light everything looking from inside to outside would appear to be in slow motion and everything looking outside inside would also appear to be in slow motion because there is no `Point Zero` reference and it's relative speeds of one to another.

Comment: That's exactly what I said! Did you read my comment?

Comment: you said that from inside out it time seems to go faster. time slows down for both sides. its a derivative of the twin paradox. the solution innvolves impulse systems etc, but certainly not what you said!

Comment: No! What you just said is not what I said earlier. Tine does not slow down both inside and outside the spaceship, just on the inside so it looks like the rest of the universe is going faster! Stay in school!

Comment: I've edited Shingetsu's first comment to be less abrasive.  @HappyBirthdayRobot read up on [twin paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox) that Shingetsu mentioned.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayRobot ... Let's say you have a train, moving near the speed of light. For a person on that train, everything in the train seems normal but everything outside the train seems to be slow, because for the train the whole world is moving at near the speed of light. Vice versa, from the outside, things on the train appear to be slow, because the train is moving, relatively to the outside, at a speed near the speed of light. Please don't urge someone to go back to school when you have your facts wrong. Here's an example of a source: http://www.squidoo.com/relativity_explanation

Comment: @HappyBirthdayRobot also, MY POINT is that what I said is NOT what you said earlier. Because what you said earlier is incorrect. When you sau "No! What you just said is not what I said earlier." You're proving my point.

Comment: @Shingetsu, Look I'm not trying to fight with you, but you need to go back and read what you wrote, in your example, the people in the train appear slow and the people outside the train appear slow, that doesn't make sense! One would appear slow the other would appear fast. Time inside the ship slows down so from the outside they looks slow and vice versa. A good sci-fi example of this is the Planet of the Apes film.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayRobot thats the point. time appears to slow from both sides. relativity seems to contradict the rules of the universe how we percieve them, but only because we live at very small speeds. read up on the subject, there are many freaky things. distance changes, mass changes, time slows for both sides. I for one actually do physics

Comment: @Shingetsu, I for one have a degree in physics! No I'm not joking I actually have a physics degree and I can tell you're not doing well in class! Look I'll send you an e-mail and explain everything in detail.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayRobot seems physics degrees don't count for much then. I've been nominated, and named, best student because of what I do in physics. I prefer the chaos theory and quantum mechanics which are partly based of restricted relativity. anyway, let us continue this by email: andrey.kudryavtsev@gmail.com . although I know I'm right in this case

Comment: @Shingetsu, no you are absolutely not right, if you go back and read through what you wrote you'll see that your statements contradict themselves. If you read through what you've written you'll find where you contradicted yourself and basically rephrased what I said and called me wrong. I don't think you're stupid but you obviously typed fast and didn't stop to check what you'd written and you're too stubborn to see for yourself. Thanks for your e-mail, I'll send you one when I have some free time.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayRobot once again. no. my statements seem to contradict themselves, however it actually is how relativity works! with delta(v) between two systems of near c, looking from any side into another gamma is small -> time appears to slow down. read up on the twin paradox. both twins percieve the other as aging more slowly.

Comment: @HappyBirthdayRobot however, the reason one actually ages less is either because he changes acceleraton - when he turns back, or gravitational acceleration of the other one, depends on the theory.

Comment: @Shingetsu, hold your horses I'm sending you the e-mail.

Comment: After a rather lengthy conversation by email we have reached a conclusion that, although in relativity theory I am correct, in the practical events of start trek (instant communication) no time slowing effects are seen and as such this answer is perfectly correct in the context of this work of fiction.

Comment: After an e-mail conversation with Shingetsu we agree that although the effect (especially within the make believe story of Star Trek) would appear as I described his physics and mathematics are flawless.